# Android 12 crash after reciving OneSignal notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-manifest, onesignal

I have exported in AndroidManifest.xml, but when I reciving notification from OneSignal. I have crashed.

and this is my code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.labz.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2m.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
    
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
    
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
    
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:replace="android:exported">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS"
        android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <service android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:node="merge"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.labz.aaa" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter> -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="aaa.page.link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="aaa.page.link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

  
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="AAAAAAAAAA"/>
    <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="true" />

</application>
```

Previously before update minSDK the crash not appear. it's running normal. but after My project update minSDK android, the crash is appear.

currently I change exported to false then the crash not appear but the notification not appear. And I check the OneSignal dashboard the status is delivery.

Please help me.. Thank you.

Comment: We need more information here, what exception do you get?